# how to test unsubscribeFocus & unsubscribeBlur with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

i got an error with this message :

> TypeError: this.unsubscribeFocus is not a function Jest

what i want to test is this code

```
componentWillUnmount() {
        // Remove the event listener
        this.unsubscribeFocus();
        this.unsubscribeBlur();
    }
```

then on file test.js

```
    test('componentWillUnmount as expected', async () => {
      class Foo extends React.Component {
        // constructor(props) {
        //   this.unsubscribeFocus = jest.fn();
        //   this.unsubscribeFocus = jest.fn();
        // }

        unsubscribeFocus = () => {};
        unsubscribeBlur = () => {};
    
        render() {
          return (<ReservationNotFound />)
        }
      }
      wrapper.unmount();
      const componentWillUnmount = wrapper.instance().componentWillUnmount();
      expect(componentWillUnmount).not.toEqual(null);
    });
  });
```

but at the wrapper.unmount i got an error that like this

[image]

so how to solve this unsubscribeFocus & unsubscribeBlur with jest when it will unmount?

Comment: Looks like it's a Redux issue and it was discussed on their Git https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/28

Comment: Are you using `enzyme`?

Comment: @LinDu yes i do use ```enzyme```

Comment: How did you render your component? Shallow render or full render?